# How to install Nvidia cuDNN on Ubuntu 20.10?

Tags: nvidia, cuda, 20.10

from the installation guide: https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/cudnn/install-guide/index.html#download, there only seems to be support for Ubuntu versions up to 20.04. However, there also is cuDNN Library for Linux (aarch64sbsa) and cuDNN Library for Linux (x86_64), although I'm not sure if I should use these.

How would you install the cuDNN safely on Ubuntu 20.10? I have the latest CUDA version (11.1).

Answer (score 1):

you can actually install from the apt repo now

```
sudo apt install nvidia-cudnn
```